# Flask Datetime: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm having troubles with flask.

```
@productivity.route('/productivity', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def productivity_view():
    today = date.today()
```

I get this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `date` to be able to use it in your function.

```
from datetime import date
```

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Have you used `date` as a local variable in any other part of the code?

Comment: Hey guys I solved. I was passing a variable to jinja called date. That was the problem. Thank you very much.